# Plural of "syntax"

Tags: grammatical-number

What is the plural of *syntax*? Would it be *syntacies*?  What rule would govern this kind of construction?

Comment: General reference - there are many ["different syntaxes"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22different+syntaxes%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only one plural form for the word itself.

Comment: Related: [Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use) I'd like to specifically quote this passage: "Unless you are absolutely, completely sure you know the correct classical plural, use the English plural. Using the classical plural may have a nice ring to it, but if you get it wrong it's so, so wrong."

Comment: Oh, and closing this as general reference because you can just [look it up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/syntax) in a dictionary.

Comment: @RegDwigнt: Neither Merriam-Webster, Dictionary.com, the OED or the ODO specify any plural for this word, so Wiktionary is quite alone in that trait.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As FumbleFingers has commented, the plural is *syntaxes*.

That's probably because the normal plural *-es* is added to the root word, **or** it may possibly be because the Greek/Late Latin word from which *syntax* is derived is *syntaxis* and Greek words ending in *-is* are pluralised with *-es*.

If we were to create a spoof plural for *syntax* it would be *syntaces* (words ending *-x* get *-ces*; the preceding vowel can change as in *index/indices*). But no-one uses that, or would know what it meant.

Answer (score 10):

An *erroneous* plural, which I offer for comparison is:

> **syntagma**

It has a rough comparability in frequency to the less exotic, more naturally English sounding '**syntaxes**'.

[image: ngram comparison of syntaxes and syntagma]

This is erroneous as a plural of 'syntax' because it is [a linguistic term](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/syntagma) having to do with rule based things but it is not a word to describe a multiplicity of a collection of rules. 'Syntagma' is a sequence of words that form a syntactic unit (for example, a noun phrase), a -single- syntactic constituent (no rule or rules, the plurality is in the (expected) number of words).

Note: I have no explanation whatsoever of the shifted character of the graphs.

Comment: At a guess? Computer Science. In linguistics, you may not need to discuss multiples of a syntax very much, but it is exceedingly common when discussing programming languages, APIs, etc. And here, 'syntaxes' rules the day, being simple and intuitive to English speakers, and English being the _lingua franca_ of CS.