# "Stadiums" vs. "stadia"

Tags: etymology, nouns, grammatical-number, latin, morphology

I'm not that old, but when I was a child/teen, *stadia* was the common term.  As in:

> - Wembley, the Nou Camp, and the Santiago Bernabeu are football stadia.
> - The MCG and Lord's are cricket stadia.

But now *stadiums* is the more common term. Is this shift essentially redundant? I've read some sources say that it better reflects English language pluralisation, but then I think "so what?" *Stadia* better reflects the Latin root, and English isn't a wholly logical/systematic language (very few languages are). If we call more than one dog *dogs*, more than one ox *oxen*, and use *cattle* both as singular and plural, then why does it matter?

Comment: <snark>Stadia sounds like a cross between an STD and a parasite</snark>. Sorry :/

Comment: How can a shift in usage be _redundant_? That doesn't make any sense to me… do you just mean that it's _unnecessary_? If so, then yes, obviously. Any shift in usage is ultimately unnecessary, though it may help to regularise the language, as we are all constantly attempting to do when we use it.

Comment: Related: [Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use)

Comment: As an American, stadiums is greatly preferred.

Comment: The stadion (plural stadia) is also a Greek unit of length (from 150-200 meters).

Comment: It's redundant because the case for the change IMO is weak.  Much o modern Standard English is not regular, so again what is the point?

Comment: TIL the word *stadia*, and that you must be older than I am: [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stadiums%2Cstadia&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstadiums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstadia%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 2):

The increase in use of *stadiums* as plural instead of *stadia* is probably also due to the fact that *stadia* has also other meanings unrelated to stadium:

[Stadia, Stadium](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stadia%2C%20stadium%2C%20Stadia%2C%20Stadium&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstadia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cstadium%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CStadia%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CStadium%3B%2Cc0): Ngram:

> - ***Both stadia and stadiums are accepted plurals of stadium. Neither is right or wrong, but stadiums is far more common.***  This is the case throughout the English-speaking world, and it has been for several decades.
> - English-speakers are not required to know the rules of Latin grammar, and most Latin-derived words with long histories in English are now pluralized in the English manner. We do still prefer some Latin plurals by convention, however, but stadia is not one of them. ***Besides, stadia has its own meanings unrelated to stadium (i.e., a telescopic instrument used to measure distances, plus several related definitions), so keeping it separate might be useful.***

([grammarist.com](http://grammarist.com/usage/stadiums-stadia/))

Comment: *Besides, stadia has its own meanings unrelated to stadium (i.e., a telescopic instrument used to measure distances*  Hmmm, but the use of stadium (or rather its Greek/Latin forebears) to mean an arena for sporting contests derives from its meaning as a standard unit of distance.  I suppose today we might coin the word "fourhectometrium" to denote an arena with a standard-length running track.

Comment: The general public has no clue that a *stadia* is a telescopic instrument, so I doubt that this has anything to do with the shift in the plural. The same shift is happening in [fulcra/fulcrums](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fulcrums%2Cfulcra&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfulcrums%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfulcra%3B%2Cc0), and *fulcra* doesn't mean anything besides the plural of *fulcrum*.

Comment: i just think stadia better reflects the Latin origin of the word.  And unless most persons are geographers or construction workers, I doubt they would confuse the Maracana, Dodgers' stadium, or the SCG with a measuring instrument..

Answer (score -2):

Stadia is a more general, abstract pluralisation. "How are stadia constructed?".

Stadiums is more literal and specific - "How many stadiums were used in the World Cup in Brazil in 2014?"

Comment: Can you justify, or support by evidence, the differences you see between the words ?

Comment: I still disagree.