# What is the plural of the word formula

Tags: grammatical-number

I study mathematics and as I'm sure you can imagine, often read the word *formula*. I also quite often come across *formulas* used as the plural. This always annoys me as I was under the impression that the correct plural of *formula* was *formulae*?

Is there any consensus or information as to why there is two (seemingly) accepted forms of this? I thought that *formulae* probably has a Latin derivation and *formulas* may be Americanized?

Comment: I would advise checking the journal where one expects to have one’s work published to see which convention they follow.

Comment: @tchrist I was more just interested. I think I will stubbornly stick my archaic ways and use formulae!

Comment: I don’t know why you write *Americanized* when you mean *naturalized*.  You seem to associate “Americanize” with the idea of doing something you don’t like, as though it were *bastardize* instead.  That isn’t very constructive.  In any event, sometimes one has two different plurals in play with slightly different meanings or registers, as occurs with *index* supporting *indices* in technical contexts and *indexes* in non-technical ones.

Comment: @tchrist Quite possibly. Although I don't think it is fair to say that I associate Americanize as something I don't like. In this instance I don't like formulas, so if it had been an Americanized word then this would be a specific example that I do not like. It does seem, to me, quite a jump to then say that I am associating Americanize with bastardize in general.

Comment: @tchrist As to your second point in your comment, I was not aware of this sort of thing so thanks!

Comment: Related: [Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/) Actually expressly covers *formulas* vs. *formulae*, too.

Comment: Do you 'stick with' cruces (for cruxes) and gymnasia? One soon learns that one's as idiosyncratic as all the rest of the illogical and disrespectful so-and-sos.

Comment: An [NGram of usage over the past half-century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formulas%2Cformulae&year_start=1958&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformulas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulae%3B%2Cc0) confirms my expectation that the irregular ***formulae*** continues to lose ground. So go for ***formulas*** unless you're constrained by some style guide, editor, educational establishment, or whatever.

Answer (score 15):

It appears that the plural [formulas](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/formula) has become the most common term also in scientific context:

> for·mu·la /ˈfɔːmjʊlə/: 
>   - n. pl. for·mu·las or for·mu·lae.

***[Usage note](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/formula):***

> - The word formula has two possible plural forms, formulae and formulas. The traditional distinction is that formulas should be used in general writing and formulae in mathematical and scientific contexts, **but analysis of the Oxford English Corpus shows that formulas is increasingly the dominant form in both technical and general uses.** (ODO)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=many%20formula%2Cmany%20formulas%2Cmany%20formulae&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmany%20formula%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20formulas%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmany%20formulae%3B%2Cc0) and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=formula%20are%2C%20formulas%20are%2Cformulae%20are&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cformula%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulas%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cformulae%20are%3B%2Cc0): 
the   graphs suggest that the most common use is 'formulas'.