# Plural of "camera obscura"

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

While reading an article about history and use of the *camera obscura* and *camera lucida* the use of *camera obscuras* for the plural felt increasingly wrong.  (whinge over)

In general when a (foreign) noun-adjective phrase is used in English the noun take the plural (*aides-de-camp*, *adjutants general*, etc.)¹.  TFD cites "Random House Kernerman Webster's College Dictionary" for the plural *camera obscuras*, which is also given in wiktionary without citation; no other dictionaries online list a plural.

Of course, *camera* as an English word derived from the Latin *camera = chamber* has the plural *cameras*, but that doesn't mean *cameras obscura* would be right because in the phrase *camera* is still Latin.  So should we be using *camerae obscurae*?  This is stated in wikipedia without citation. Have I even got the plurals right in Latin? Probably not, I haven't studied Latin for nearly 25 years.  Should we semi-anglicise it to *cameras obscura*?

¹There are many more words and phrases which take the plural in the middle in the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/8450/48571).

["Which style of Latin plurals should I use?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/9004/48571) is relevant but doesn't provide an answer to what we should do in the case of a phrase.  I would even say that it might support "cameras obscura" which nothing else does.

Comment: Given by Wiktionary; RHK Webster's.

Comment: I was unconvinced by RHK Websters cited through TFD, hence my question (though I abbreviated it differently to you).  As for wiktionary (I must admit I didn't check there specifically) with no citation I'm not inclined to treat it as independent of the one I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Also -- wikipedia disagrees but lacks a citation.

Comment: Do whichever or whatever you want. There are no set rules for this. And even if there were you could break them. This isn't French. Are you of the kind that orders three whoppers junior or three whopper juniors? Squirrels to the nuts and nuts to the squirrels. Just don't say octopi.

Comment: @pazzo spaghetti !

Comment: That's right. @YohannV. Everyone in USA but Italian-Americans call the meal lasagna, which is patently wrong, since it takes more than one lasagna to make lasagne.

Comment: @pazzo I'm hungry and angry now !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which style of Latin plurals should I use?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use)

Comment: I didn't recognise your abbreviations (I'm dealing with a roof repairer at the moment); TFD is non-standard and Random House a publishing company, perhaps with a style guide.//  If a variant is given in two dictionaries, and no others give alternatives, I'd go with the obvious. This choice is supported by [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=camera+obscuras%2Ccameras+obscura%2Ccamarae+obscurae&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccamera%20obscuras%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccameras%20obscura%3B%2Cc0). I'm surprised this usage is so old.

Comment: @Mari-LouA can we go with "related" for 2 reasons: The question you link deals only with single words, not phrases; following on from that, if we accept that we should use an English plural, how should we form it (Attorneys-general etc.)?

Comment: I believe the principles which are outlined in the answers can be applied directly to your Latin example

Comment: Google Books claims 3280 written instances of [*camera obscuras*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22camera+obscuras%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but only 444 for [*cameras obscura*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22cameras+obscura%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Fairly obviously the former is far more common, and you wouldn't normally expect dictionaries to list "regular" plural forms like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I wasn't seriously proposing *cameras obscura*, but pointing out that it fits a pattern. I would have thought (I'm apparently wrong) that this is a case in which there is some doubt as to what the regular form would actually be and that the dictionary *should* confirm it, given the more common case of noun-adjective phrases in which the noun takes the plural.

Comment: @Chris: I'm quite surprised to see that 50% of all writers seem to have [doggedly stuck with ***adjutants general***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=adjutant+generals%2Cadjutants+general&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cadjutant%20generals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cadjutants%20general%3B%2Cc0). I'd have expected the more "regular" ***adjutant generals*** to have eventually come to dominate, but it's been pretty much neck-and-neck for at least a couple of centuries now.

Comment: ...by [strict rules](http://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/plurals_forming_compound_nouns.htm), we ought to use ***cameras obscura*** in your case. That's because *camera* is the "principal" word (and the *noun*), so it should work like *sons-in-law*. But there's a degree of uncertainty (as with *court-martials* for a significant proportion of writers) because these are effectively "foreign compound words", so native speakers aren't really sure which is the more important word. Consequently, they tend to apply the generic default pluralisation (stick the ***s*** on the *end*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *adjutants general* isn't as good an example as the (presumably more common) *attorneys general* or *courts-martial*, but I was struggling to come up with examples, I could only think of simple  French phrases that aren't used in English.  Incidentally *court-martial* behaves slightly differently for 2 reasons: the hyphen, and the use as a verb; similarly *son-in-laws* is also seen (no point in an NGram if I understand correctly how it would handle the rather common possessive *son-in-law's*.

Comment: The possessive ***'s*** isn't a problem in Google Books (where there are 1.5M instances of [*mothers-in-law*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mothers-in-law%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)). The 1100 instances of [*mother-in-laws*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mother-in-laws%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) ("incorrect" for both possessive *and* plural) are indexed separately from 20,000 [*mother-in-law's*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22mother-in-law+s%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), because the apostrophe is treated as if it were a space.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I just realised that while playing around with your *adjutant[s] general[s]* NGram.  I remembered that it struggled with punctuation but didn't know exactly how.

Comment: In the long run, *Indian* usage will probably come to dominate (just as currently, American usage dominates what was originally the *British* language, by sheer weight of numbers). At the very least, Indian usage will have far more influence in future, and I have the distinct impression from looking at Google Books results for the supposedly incorrect (but more "standard", in the grand scheme of morphology) ***son-in-laws*** that this version is far more likely among Indians than Anglophones at large (but I do realise they're mostly not *native* speakers as yet! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camera_obscura) :

> **Etymology**
>
> New Latin, from **camera**, *chamber*, + **obscura**, *dark*.
>
> **Noun**
>
> camera obscura (plural camera obscuras)

---

You can find example of usage in [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura) :

> Most practical **camera obscuras** use a lens rather than a pinhole (as in a pinhole camera) because it allows a larger aperture, giving a usable brightness while maintaining focus.

This is a [book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_obscura#cite_note-18) in references :

> 17. Smith, Roger. "A Look Into Camera Obscuras". Retrieved 2014-10-23.

There is a website :

> [Cameraobscuras.com](http://www.cameraobscuras.com/) George T Keene builds custom camera obscuras like the Griffith Observatory CO in Los Angeles.

And this is also a category : [Camera_obscuras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Camera_obscuras)

---

The funny part is that [camera](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/camera#Etymology) in english came from this.

Comment: I was editing this into the question at the same time as you were writing your answer -- it copies the unconvincing definition only given in one relatively minor source.

Comment: @ChrisH Edited my answer.

Comment: You've found a few more sources, but note that the wikipedia article is inconsistent.

Comment: @ChrisH wiktionary or wikipedia? If you can read, [hebrew article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%9E%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94) is nice

Comment: Wikipedia uses both "camera obscuras" and "camerae obscurae".  I like the second, I trust neither.

Comment: @ChrisH `The term is based on the Latin camera, "(vaulted) chamber or room", and obscura, "darkened" (plural: camerae obscurae).` This is **Latin** as you said. It is not the usage in **English**. (The other mention is by a french, in a french museum.) Do as you want, but I find wiki totally fine.

Comment: I've accepted your conclusion, though it wasn't the body of your answer that finally convinced me.  OED 1st ed from archive.org doesn't give a plural but does have a citation for "Camera obscuras" from 1796.  I'd given up on the 200+MB pdf but tried again.

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate reaction probably arises from other phrases such as court martial and inspector general. The difference is that these phrases are derived from French, and already have plurals associated with them (courts martial and inspectors general). The term camera obscura seems to have originated with Kepler in 1604, and the term spread as a fixed phrase. As a result, in English the plural is formed by simply adding an s to the final word: camera obscuras.

Comment: Wikipedia credits Kepler but the cited source actually mentions Herschel. Or would make sense for Herschel, who worked in England, to have introduced the term to English; Kepler on the other hand wrote in Latin and lived mainly in German-speaking countries. He may of course have coined the term. I tagged the discrepancy earlier. I reckon I could find a Latin example though I can't think of one off the top of my head.