# Plural of Latin masculine nouns ending in -o; eg. "folio"

Tags: grammatical-number, latin

Most discussions I have read on the issue of Latin plurals in English only address words ending in -us, -um, -x and the feminine nouns ending in -a. I would like to know how to make the English plural of Latin masculine nouns ending in -o, such as "folio". I am tempted to say and write "folia" as the plural of "folio", and similarly "bifolia" as the plural of "bifolio" etc, although my Oxford Advanced Learner's only quotes "folios". I am sure I have read both versions of this plural in academic print before. What would you advise?

Comment: In what sense are you using the word?

Comment: Merriam-Webster has given their own view on how to form plurals with Latin-derived nouns (paraphrasing): "When a word from a foreign language is taken into English, forming the plural as you would with other English nouns becomes fair game; the word is, after all, now an English word. Hence the plural of octopus is octopuses (but you can use octopi or (more appropriately) octopodes if you want to)."

Answer (score 20):

I would advise using the only plural form that you found listed in your dictionary (and in general, following the [advice given by arnsholt](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9004/which-style-of-latin-plurals-should-i-use/9095#9095) in an answer to a related question: "Unless you are absolutely, completely sure you know the correct classical plural, or the classical plural is the normal plural, use the English plural").

The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=folio&allowed_in_frame=0) explains that this word is derived from the ablative singular form of the Latin word *folium* "leaf, page." It does not come from a Latin noun that ends in "o" in the nominative singular.

That said, there are words like that (such as *ratio*; this is actually feminine in Latin, but it is in the third declension so it doesn't really affect how  you pluralize it). Many of them have "n" in their other forms in Latin (the Latin plural of *ratio* is *rationes*). I've never heard or seen anyone use plurals like "rationes" in English. In my experience, people always use "ratios." (In *[Grammar of the Latin Language](https://books.google.com/books?id=1VYEAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=Latin%20nouns%20ending%20in%20o%20ratio&source=bl&ots=8uQfowgagp&sig=B7DoY6GKzF04BbRbi8MJgpnUQxs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiksJOMrJDPAhVI6IMKHbYzDBkQ6AEIUzAJ#v=onepage&q=Latin%20nouns%20ending%20in%20o%20ratio&f=false),* by Leonhard Schmitz, I found a masculine example: *pugio* "knife," plural in Latin *pugiones.*)

Comment: Most hominids can think of a third-declension masculine ending in *-o*. :)

Comment: @tchrist: well, I was trying to think of a Latin word ending in "-o" that has become naturalized in English.

Comment: I’m thinking *homo* probably doesn’t fit that bill. :)

Comment: Arguably, if you wanted to use the Latinate plural, it should be _foliis_. But such forms are follies.

Comment: Older law books talk about rationes decidendi but there "ratio" is a Latin word meaning "reason".

Answer (score 10):

The [Latin word was *folium*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/folium#Latin), a neuter singular whose plural was *folia*. The ablative case was *folio*, and that is what the English word is borrowed from during the Late Latin period.

There is no reason not to use the regular English plural, *folios*. I have never seen anything else except for purely Latin formulations like *folia botanica*, which is clearly meant to be Latin not English.

Answer (score -2):

Since *folio* itself is not a Latin word, there *is* no Latin plural. I would say that *folio* is Anglicized Italian. At any rate, it is English, so the plural is simply *folios*.

Comment: "Folio" *is* a Latin word; it's just not in the nominative.

Comment: @jwodder: actually, the Oxford English Dictionary says it may also be (at least in part) from Italian "foglio." [Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/folio) also mentions "foglio" as a possible source.

Comment: Whether or not Italian usage influenced the English borrowing doesn't change the fact that `folio` is a Latin word.

Comment: @chepner: depends on what you mean by "word," I suppose. It is a word-form that could be found in a Latin text, but it is not a Latin lemma (it wouldn't be listed as a headword in a Latin dictionary).

Comment: @suməlic: I'm not sure why that's relevant. If a creole has a word "wen" derived from English *went*, would you argue that *went* is "not an English word" just because English lexicographers have selected the bare infinitive, in this case *go*, as the lemma?